# Suricata rule to allow ntp from specific URL

Tags: suricata

Is there a way to allow only port UDP 123(NTP) from certain domain eg time.aws.com ? Currently I am using this rule - pass ntp $HOME_NET any → $EXTERNAL_NET 123 (sid:4001; rev:1;) but wanted to tie it down to specific URL

I want to use time.aws.com on NTP as allowed domain

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
drop ntp $HOME_NET any → $EXTERNAL_NET 123 (msg:"Message"; content:!"time.aws.com";sid:4001; rev:1;)
```

According to [suricata documentation](https://docs.suricata.io/en/suricata-6.0.0/rules/payload-keywords.html?highlight=operators#content), you can negate that content, meaning any content that is not the one specified will be dropped.